# css / html - no-wrap equivalent for div / auto width of element container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image slider / viewer in which an absolutely positioned div containing a bunch of images sits inside a relative div of a fixed width. The problem is that the images appear one below another inside the absolutely positioned div, instead of next to each other horizontally - even though they are given the property float:left; - How do I prevent them from wrapping (similar to how you prevent text from doing so via the no-wrap property? Can I give the absolutely positioned div a width property that encompasses all of its elements without calculating that width via javascript? Here's code:

```
<div id="homeSlider" style="width:800px; position:relative;">
    <div id="homeSlides" style="position:absolute;">
        <img class="homeSlide" src="images/temp-portfolio.jpg" alt="Portfolio Item"/>
        <img class="homeSlide" src="images/temp-portfolio.jpg" alt="Portfolio Item"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be able to set the width of `#homeSlides` to a large value (e.g. 10000px) without problems, just do it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks - I know it's weird and unnecessary, but I'd rather be precise

Comment: Can you provide jsFiddle? In the example you posted images are placed horizontally.

Comment: They should be placed horizontally, but because the width of homeSlides is constrained to the width of homeSlider, the homeSlide items won't float horizontally next to each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do (if possible in your case) is to set the `img` items to `display: inline-block` and then set the `homeSlides` to have `white-space: nowrap`, and avoid `float` all together.

[**See fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RXEwQ/1/)